# PHP not inserting data into MySQL but not showing error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to input data into a MySQL Database using PHP and a HTML Form but the data isn't saved into the database even though it shows that it has. Please show me how to ensure the form entries save to the database.

HTML

```
<form action="newproduct.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input name="user" type="text"></td>
</tr> ...

<button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$dbname = "bakefree_products";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
  
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$_POST["range"]." (productname, image, frompricesize, paypalcode, productdesc, allergystandard, allergyglutenfree, allergyvegan, allergygfvegan)
VALUES ('".$_POST["productname"]."', '".$_POST["image"]."', '".$_POST["frompricesize"]."', '".$_POST["paypalcode"]."', '".$_POST["productdesc"]."', '".$_POST["allergystandard"]."', '".$_POST["allergyglutenfree"]."', '".$_POST["allergyvegan"]."', '".$_POST["allergygfvegan"]."')";

    
        
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New product created successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
    
//show new number of products
$sql = "SELECT * FROM".$_POST["range"];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {echo "There are ".$result->num_rows ." products.";
} else {
    echo "<br><br>There are no products in ".$_POST["range"];
}
    
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

RESULT

> New product created successfully.
>
> There are no products in TEST

Comment: Your `SELECT` query is failing because you have no space between `FROM` and the table name.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This solved it!

Comment: your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, why you are reading the table name from the user input?!

Answer (score 0):

Actually insertion should be working fine but you need to check the syntax of the select query here,

```
//show new number of products
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_POST["range"]; // Added a space after `FROM`
```

And it should fetch data properly and show you the string, `There are X products.`

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions which are just simple typos. Instead, make a comment (as I have already done) and flag the question as "off-topic" due to a non-reproducible or typographical error. Questions like this add no value to the site and will eventually be deleted, thus causing you to lose any reputation that you may gain from answering.

Comment: ohk, removing in a min.

Comment: Also known as answer stealing for quick rep, cancerous, answer still not deleted!!